# Tooltip javascript disrupts following form element when "title" attribute not given

Tags: forms, tooltip, javascript

I'm using a javascript tooltip provided by jqueryTOOLS to give tool tips within a form.

For some form elements that do not require a tool tip I want to leave the title string blank, however if I do this then it causes disruption in the subsequent elements of the form - almost as if it is treating them as a tool tip: on mouseover an element with no title string it moves the following element's position to hover next to the field, then when no longer focused it disappears permanently.

My tooltip code:

```
$(function() {
$("#myform :input").tooltip({
position: "center right",
offset: [-2, 10],
effect: "fade",
opacity: 0.7
  });
});
```

As you have probably guessed this tool tip is based on the 'title' attribute of a field.

After having included

```
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

in the header.

Hopefully my description of events made sense!

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: paste your code here or on jsfiddle and provide the link.

Comment: @CoreyRS I can tell you though that the last element in the last element in the page (the 'next' submit button) which has no title attrabute and therefore no tooltip gives a page error:

`Uncaught Cannot find tooltip for [object Object] jquery.tools.min.js:102
e.extend.show jquery.tools.min.js:102
(anonymous function) jquery.tools.min.js:101
f.each.f.event.special.(anonymous function).handle jquery.tools.min.js:37
f.event.dispatch jquery.tools.min.js:37
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery.tools.min.js:37`

Comment: @CoreyRS - couldn't get jsfiddle to replicate my issue - but here is a stripped down version of my code exhibing the same behaviour as I experience:
http://piratepad.net/RdgiC71lOt

3 questions, questions 1 & 3 have title attributes which appear as a tool tip. Question 2 was left with no tool tip. Clicking in the second field repositions the 3rd field and then removes it, just as if Q3 was a tooltip itself. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

The trigger element was defined to all inputs, so it was using the next  as a tooltip in the lack of a title element.

Just a bug on the party of jqueryTOOLS but an easy solution:

replace

```
$("#myform :input")
```

with

```
$("#myform :input[title]")
```

Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 3):

I fixed a problem giving me the same error, but in a different context:

I had a table with two columns, both colums containing tooltips (a `DIV` in the corresponding `TD`).

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="tooltip"></div></td>
      <td><div class="tooltip"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When opening the tooltip in the first column, the height and width of the second column `TD` change (as if that `TD` was the tooltip).

Adding an extra empty `DIV` element after the tooltip `DIV` in the `TD` of the first column solved the problem.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="tooltip"></div>
        <div></div> <!-- extra empty div -->
      </td>
      <td><div class="tooltip"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```